# Unable to access object in site.com issue

Tags: site.com

I want to add a data Repeater element and when I create data connection for candidate object an internal error occurred.Below are the steps which I follow:

1) [image: click menu to select page element] 
2) [image: clicked to add data repeater]

3) [image: selected candidate object]

4) [image: And this error occured]

please help me how to resolve this problem and why this problem is coming.

Comment: You need to contact salesforce support for that sort of errors. One thing that comes to mind is if the object has any fields that site.com does not handle properly, maybe the geolocation field?

Comment: you are right ,salesforce does not support geo location field on site.com.

Comment: Looks like a known issue, you can track the fix here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0kKAAS